# Redirect URL with index.php to an ASP.NET page instead

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, .net-4.5

In converting a website from PHP to .NET, I want to be able to support old URLs and redirect them to the new MVVM. Such links are embedded in documents, Wikis, forum posts etc, plus users have bookmarks, so it's not feasible to just convert everything during migration.

So in App_Start RouteConfig RegisterRoutes I have:

```
routes.MapRoute("index.php", "Home/Redirect");
```

In my Home controller I have:

```
    public ActionResult Redirect()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Redirect";

        return View();
    }
```

And Redirect.cshtml:

```
<h2>Redirect</h2>

<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
<h3>@ViewBag.Message</h3>
```

Obviously the above does very little yet, but more to the point, running it and entering

```
https://localhost:44303/index.php
```

as the URL yields a 404 error. But I thought I added a custom route, if I am understanding correctly? Do I need to register .php as a valid extension somewhere?

To summarise: URL comes in as www.mywebsite.com/index.php?param1=x&param2=y and I want to re-route to www.mywebsite.com/Home/Redirect and retain the parameters.

Please note, I am **not** asking to handle PHP: I just want to basically re-write the URL.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me add an alternative answer here for posterity as it seems neater than the accepted answer. We needed to recreate a .php site as an ASP.Net MVC site and deliver 301 redirects for the old .php pages. Here's how we solved the problem.

Step 1: add the following class to your MVC project. This isn't namespaced, so  you can put it wherever you like. We have an "infrastructure" folder for classes like this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

public class PHPRedirectHandler: IHttpHandler
{
    bool IHttpHandler.IsReusable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    void IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string originalUrl = context.Request.Url.PathAndQuery;
        int index = originalUrl.ToLower().IndexOf(".php");
        if (index >= 0)
        {
            string page = context.Request.Url.PathAndQuery;
            var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(context.Request.RequestContext);
            string newUrl;
            switch (page)
            {
                case "/about.php":
                    newUrl = urlHelper.Action("About", "Home");
                    break;
                default:
                    newUrl = urlHelper.Action("Index", "Home");
                    break;
            }
            context.Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
            context.Response.AddHeader("Location", newUrl);
            context.Response.End();
        }
    }
}
```

Step two: by default, MVC routing will try to send requests for PHP pages to a controller, so you need to explicitly ignore those requests. Find your "RegisterRoutes" method, which may be in global.asax or in the App_Start folder, and add the following to ignore all PHP requests...

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.php/{*pathInfo}");
```

Step three: finally, you'll need to tell the application to use the HTTP handler from Step one to handle .php requests. Add the following to the `<system.webServer>` section of your web.config. You may of course already have handlers set up, in which case don't add the  element.

```
<handlers>
   <add name="PHPRedirectHandler" path="*.php" verb="*" type="PHPRedirectHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
</handlers>
```

And that's all we did. Seems to work pretty well.

Comment: That looks exactly what I need - thank you. I have a weird problem though: setting a breakpoint in ProcessRequest and it gets hit if the url is index2.php, fred.php, index.php?fred=1 - but NOT if it's just index.php. Any ideas? Admittedly I've played before but I can't find any other text references to "php" anywhere in the code! It redirects itself to the root, as in "https://localhost:44303/"

Comment: Actually it's not a problem since the whole point of redirecting here is to turn the parameters after index.php into a new query string, so no parameters is unredirectable anyway. Still curious though. Anyway, accepted answer changed to this one as it perfectly answers the question. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have one solution, however I cannot pass parameters, **OR** Javascript must be enabled. Neither is ideal for me.

In the site's web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
  <staticContent>
    <remove fileExtension=".php" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".php" mimeType="text/html" />
  </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Then, in the project's root, create index.php with the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Redirecting...</title>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content ="5; url=/Home/Redirect">
</head>
<body>
Redirecting - please wait.
</body>
</html>
```

That gets it to the Home controller, Redirect method. But any parameters passed to the original request get lost.

It is apparently possible, as I said above, to use Javascript to pass the parameters but I'm not keen due to the number of users with it turned off. Using a  is also possible apparently, but some browsers may warn of a form being redirected with parameters which again isn't ideal.

Comment: Logic says I should be able to change the mimeType to process as if it was a regular ASP, ie with server side processing, but brain+Google can't compute! Any ideas?

Comment: Personally I don't have a solution that works for me fully and I don't like accepting my own answers. But maybe somebody will find the above useful.

Comment: This actually works for me. Tried the accepted answer but didn't really work for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to handle this as below.

First , have a handler in your web.config file.

```
<add name="PHPRedirectHandler" path="*.php" verb="*" type="PHPRedirectHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
```

and in your controller have the below condition. You simply check the extension, if it has .php, then remove it and redirect.

```
        if (temp_url.IndexOf(".php") != -1)
        {
            return Redirect(temp_url.Replace(".php", ""));
        }
```

Works really well for me.

Let me know if you need more explanation on this.